# How to Responsively Resize an Image According to a Fixed Width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a website in which one horizontal section is divided into two. On the left hand side is text and a button that are vertically stacked. On the right hand side is an image. On the right hand side of the screen, when the screen shrinks, I'm trying to make the image remain a fixed pixel amount that decreases its size at specific break points. On the left hand side of the screen, I want the text to take up close to half of the screen but not always precisely 50% (it would depend on the fixed image size). However, when I've tried to do this, I've consistently faced difficulties with the image on right hand side of the screen either becoming too large or small or a scroll bar appearing.

I understand this needs media queries, but what is the most effective way to accomplish these variable width and size requirements in terms of px, vw, etc?

A similar example is the Intelligent Route Planning and Fleet Management Section on this website: https://workwave.com/ which has a map to the right.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 975px) {
    .logo-img {
        width: 50vw;
    }
  }

  .logo-img {
    width: 50vw;
  }

  /* @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .logo-img {
        width: 700px;
    }
  } */

  .items {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #0f2c4d;
  }


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="items">  
            <h1>KJnjjkasdsad & asdfasdfasd dsfadfsada</h1>
            <p>Jnjasd dasklfsda dsfasd dsfklads fasd fasd asf asdlasd asdfasf asdfas asdlkmadsklmfasd fdaslmk fasd klmfasd asdklm fasdf.</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
        </div>
            <img class="logo-img" src="./images/fleet-sm.png" alt="Mountain View">
        <div></div>
        <div></div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you would just set the image to a defined pixel amount based on the media query break points? what sizing would work best for the text and button on the left hand side?

Comment: well i say you should use w3.css from w3schools for starting, use their classes , they already have classes which are responsive design ready

Answer (score 1):

You can also have different stylesheets for different media, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)" href="widescreen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="smallscreen.css">
```

use whatever css file you want based on screen size , so you can create different css and use them for specific range of widths and at break point it will change its css as you specify next css file for different width.

Also you can use media queries to change your css based on screen width.

```
//699px taken as demo
//for screen smaller than 699px 
@media screen and (max-width: 699px){
.whatever
{
//css
}
}

//for screen bigger than 699px
@media screen and (min-width: 699px){
.whatever
{
//css
}
}
```

Comment: but what do you think would be the best way to set the width of the image and the text in the media queries so it doesn't overflow or go under the screen size?

Comment: add css `.sc{width:100%; min-width:330px; height:auto;}` and add class `sc` into your `img` tag , also you have to calibrate the width yourself, for how much width do you want the img to be fixed

Comment: this would be for the text section? {width:100%; min-width:330px; height:auto}

Comment: if you think your problem is solved you can mark the question as answered.

Comment: @dog can you share you code , insert into your question , i will change it in accordance to your needs, also i should mention your question is so out of topic.

Comment: also you can apply the css for both img and text ,change min-width value for what min width you want them to fix or stop resizing with respect to screen size

Comment: i added the code i currently have. you can see the effect i'm trying to achieve on this site https://workwave.com/  in the section Intelligent Route Planning and Fleet Management Section

Answer (score 1):

On your demand, showing how to use w3.css , use this css it has classes which already have pre written media rules for different sizes for different classes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<style>
.sc
{
width:100%;height:auto;
}
</style>
    <div class="w3-container">
        <div class="w3-half">  
            <h1>KJnjjkasdsad & asdfasdfasd dsfadfsada</h1>
            <p>Jnjasd dasklfsda dsfasd dsfklads fasd fasd asf asdlasd asdfasf asdfas asdlkmadsklmfasd fdaslmk fasd klmfasd asdklm fasdf.</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-half">
            <img class="sc" src="http://www.neutelings-riedijk.com/content/images/6f711d8f7fec1c9f85dfcb5045d4f30b.jpg" alt="Mountain View">

    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: i changed your code and embedded w3.css into it you should learn about w3.css, it is an pre written css and also have pre written @media rules for different sizes , like for doing half a screen size you use class w3-half, for 1/2 use w3-onethird, for 1/4 you use w3-quarter, and never worry about resize these classes auto resize with respect to screen size.